# youtube embed playback error

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, embed

I am using a wordpress theme and on the page I am embedding a video through the plugin. I had a first error of:

embed youtube video - Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I proceeded to google and found I had to change the link to /embed

Now I have the issue of the video always having an error playback. I am stuck on this issue and cannot get it to work. I have contacted the theme admin but they are not replying so I thought I would post here.

The link is here https://brad211.000webhostapp.com/portfolio/

Select the image and the video should pop up.

The video debug file is here:

```
{
  "cpn": "G8ufOGi5ye0rbvhW",
  "vct": "0.000",
  "vd": "NaN",
  "vpl": "",
  "vbu": "",
  "vpa": true,
  "vsk": false,
  "ven": false,
  "vpr": 1,
  "vrs": 0,
  "vns": 0,
  "vec": null,
  "vvol": 0.38,
  "state": "80",
  "debug_error": {
    "errorCode": "api.invalidparam",
    "errorDetail": "invalidVideodata.1",
    "message": "An error occurred. Please try again later.",
    "messageKey": "YTP_ERROR_GENERIC_WITHOUT_LINK"
  },
  "relative_loudness": "0.000",
  "0sz": false,
  "op": "",
  "yof": false,
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "Intel(R)_Iris(TM)_Graphics_6100",
  "cgr": true,
  "debug_playbackQuality": "unknown",
  "debug_date": "Mon Mar 20 2017 11:16:09 GMT+1100 (AEDT)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the link you've provided and looked the embedded video url. It seems the you've some issue with the url of video. 
Your video url : [//www.youtube.com/embed/v/ylJSHxgAVA8](http:////www.youtube.com/embed/v/ylJSHxgAVA8)

I think the video you're trying to embbed? https://www.youtube.com/embed/ylJSHxgAVA8

Please try and check placing that link.
Thanks